# How to send message and signature as Vec<u8> and [u8; 64] to program

Tags: anchor

I'm following this repo (https://github.com/GuidoDipietro/solana-ed25519-secp256k1-sig-verification) to create and verify signature, but the way to create instruction isn't used anymore so I'm trying to do the method way.
I have a message and sign it using @noble/ed25519

```
let signature = await ed.sign(
            MSG,
            owner.secretKey.slice(0, 32)
          );
```

In program, my input type is msg: Vec, sig: [u8; 64] and after build the program, the types required are 'ArgsTuple<[{ name: "msg"; type: "bytes"; }, { name: "sig"; type: { array: ["u8", 64]; }; }]
So how can I convert these type for the function?

Answer (score 0):

For your message, assuming you want utf-8 encoding, you likely need `Buffer.from(MSG, 'utf8')`, and to make a `Vec` more specifically, you need to prefix it with the size of the msg, encoded as a `u32`, so using `buf.writeInt32LE(MSG.length)`. And then `ed.sign` already gives a `Uint8Array`, so you can just send that in as is.